# Best practices to make a sign in view at launching app on ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiwindow, launching-application

I would ask you what are the best practices to make a sign in view on ios.
And only after fetching those text fields, launch the application content.
Does I make two windows ? Apple recommended to use two windows only for external display.
If it is a good practice, how can I build this ?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I would present a modal view controller from the app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method

something like

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:signInViewController animated:NO];
```

do this after

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

then when you are finished with the sign-in view controller you can dismiss it the same as you would any modal view controller

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved either ways. It depends on your requirement. If you want to use built in navigation for with push effect than you can create two different controller.

This can also be achieved in same controller too. You can create Separate view and will be shown/hidden according to situation. In this case if you want to have animation than you have to write some piece of code for that.

**Update**

This can be done as follows.

```
-(void)loadApplication
{
    [self.navController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:NO];
}
```

1. In MainWindow.xib you take 1 navigation controller and bind it with iboutlet in application delegate. Give your login view controller as its base controller in navigation controller by expanding it.
2. In MainWindow.xib you take 1 Tabbar controller and bind it with iboutlet in application delegate.
3. In your Loginview controller have application delegate and on successfull login call `loadApplication` method accordingly. On failure you can give alert message.

Following screen is to show you how your MainWindow.xib will look like. For instance I have just given LoginViewController at each place in TabBarController. You can take any controller to suit your requirement.

In case of any query please comment. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I need to have two controllers, one for my TabBar and one other for my sign in view so I think it would be better to have two windows. But how can you switch between windows ? release them ?